# Naming a PHP Class Property With a % at the start

Tags: php

I am getting a syntax error when I try to declare my variable (%myVar) like this -

```
public $%myVar;
```

I am trying to create something dynamic, with data that requires some variable names to start with a %.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: You should read about *naming variables and the conventions*. BTW why do you need that?

Comment: Google php variable variables http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: How about an associative array? `$array['%myVar']`

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to work around this!

This are the naming conventions for PHP variables from the [official docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

> Variable names follow the same rules as other labels in PHP. A valid
>   variable name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any
>   number of letters, numbers, or underscores. As a regular expression,
>   it would be expressed thus: '[a-zA-Z_\x7f-\xff][a-zA-Z0-9_\x7f-\xff]*'

Comment: Writeing an own php interpreter is _not_ a workaround, since such interpreter would not interpret php, but some other language (which might be close to php).

Comment: @arkascha Came to my mind right before you commented, I removed that statement already :)

Comment: `${"%myVar"}` will work. Not sure if it works for class properties, however -- probably a compile time error. PHP is a funny language...

Answer (score 0):

As the php allow, you can try this `public $$myVar;` $myVar is the dynamic what you want.

Comment: Eh, nope. Variable variables cannot be used as class properties. They are evaluated at run-time; classes are read at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with the help of [variable properties](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) you can do something like this:

```
$varName = '%myVar';
$test = new stdClass;
$test->$varName = 'ok';
var_dump($test);
```

But if you ask me, that's totally ugly. Try to respect the conventions :)